# Como traducir pronombres reflexivos ("myself", "yourself", "ourselves", etc.)

Tags: traducción, pronombres

Yo creo que puedo traducir algunos pronombres reflexivos, por ejemplo:

> Yo lo quiero hacer por mí mismo. ***(mí mismo -> myself)***
>
> Él no podía hacerlo por sí mismo. ***(sí mismo -> himself, herself, itself)***

¿Pero cómo traduciría pronombres como estos que son plurales?

- ourselves -> *nos mismo??*
- themselves -> *sí mismos??*
- yourselves -> *sí mismos??*

Y si pudieran usar los pronombres en algunas frases como ejemplos sería perfecto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es importante tener en cuenta que **a veces**, cuando se usa en español la palabra **mismo(s)** tras un pronombre, es en general cuando en inglés se usó la preposición **by** antes del pronombre.

La traducción de esos pronombres es:

- ourselves

  - nos
  - nosotros mismos

> When we find **ourselves** with a large shop
>   Cuando **nos** encontramos con una gran tienda
>
> We had to carry our equipment and supplies **by ourselves**.
>   Tuvimos que cargar nuestro equipo y los suministros **por nosotros mismos**.

- themselves

  - sí mismos

> Standardisation and harmonisation do not add value **by themselves**.
>   La normalización y la armonización no añaden valor **por sí mismas**.
>
> It will of course be up to the groups to organize **themselves**.
>   Por supuesto que los propios grupos deberán organizarse a **sí mismos**.

- yourselves

  - ustedes mismos

> Do not try to diagnose postpartum depression **by yourselves**.
>   No trate de diagnosticar **por ustedes mismos** la depresión postparto.
>
> Do not be afraid to ask **yourselves** these questions!
>   ¡No tengan miedo de hacerse estas preguntas a **ustedes mismos**!

---

<sup>Ejemplos tomados de www.linguee.com</sup>